# How do i get highest price index?

Tags: java

I have an issue about how do I get highest price Number in main class with class object ??

In `getNumber` function I only want to pass price and return number and in main i am creating 4 object with number which is auto increment and price so I want the highest price in which index it's located.i want to know that which position highest price is.

```
Product.java import java.util.*;    
import java.lang.*;     
import java.io.*;

    class Product {

        static int counter = 0;

        int num;

        double price;

        TestCode() {
            Counter++;
            num = Counter;
        }

        int getNumber(double price) {
            // what should i write here to get the number from price?
            return num;
        }

    }

    }
```

Main.java

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.lang.*; 
import java.io.*;

/* Todo;: get number which has highest price */

Class Main {
    Public static void main(String args[]) {
        int highestPrice = 0;
        Product prod;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i) {

            prod = new Product();
                // What should I write here
              If(highestPrice > prod.getPrice()){
                   highestPrice = prod.getPrice()
              }

            System.out.println("highest price index at "+ prod.getNumber(highestPrice));

}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. Return the highest price of what? Of a single object? What does `num` represent? What do you want to return in `getNumber`?

Comment: Also, your code is far from being valid Java code. Fix all the errors printed by the compiler.

Comment: In getNumber function i only want to pass price and return number and in main i am creating 4 object with number which is auto increment and price so I want the highest price in which index it's located.i want to know that which position highest price is.

Comment: why do you use two points instead of a semicolon in some of yours lines of code (i really don t know )?

Comment: @GBlodgett num is for index i am using static index which is common for all object so that I store the counter to maintain the index

Comment: This code still will not compile.

Comment: This won't work. `prod` is one object. It knows its `num` and its `price` but it doesn't know the `num` of the object with `highestPrice`. You have to set something like `numOfHighestPrice = i` next to `highestPrice = prod.getPrice()` in your main method. Alternatively you can use a container like a map to get `num` by `price`.

Answer (score 2):

So you have a lot of small errors here. (Remember case matters in Java)

`public` is lower case

```
 public static void main(String args[]) {
```

You haven't initialized this variable:

```
    Product prod;
```

Infinite loop here (You never increment `i`):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i) {
```

Here you keep reinitializing `prod`:

```
        prod = new Product();
```

`if` is lower case:

```
          If(highestPrice > prod.getPrice()){
               highestPrice = prod.getPrice()
          }
        System.out.println("highest price index at "+ prod.getNumber(highestPrice));
```

And in your `Product` class:

This method doesn't have a return type. And you have `counter` as upper case here. (I'm assuming you wanted it to be the same lower case variable earlier in your code

```
TestCode() {
        Counter++;  
        num = Counter;
    }
```